# BASH SCRIPT : How to use a variable inside another variable

Tags: bash

I need to store command line arguments passed in an array

my Command is

```
./test1.sh 2 4 6
```

Now i need to store 2 4 6 in an array and im using..

```
s1=$#     
"it tells how many arguments are passed."


for (( c=1; c<=$s1; c++ ))

do

     a[$c]}=${$c}
```

I have written `${$c}` for taking the arguments value but it is showing bad substition.

Answer (score 7):

This will give you an array with the arguments: `args=("$@")`

And you can call them like this: `echo ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]}`

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you mark an accepted answer, so the issue wont stay in the "unanswered" section?

Answer (score 1):

bash variable can be [indirectly referenced](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) by \$$VARNAME  or by ${!VARNAME} in [version 2](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html)
so your assignment statement must be :

```
a[$c]=${!c}
```

or

```
eval a[$c]=\$$c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always pick the first argument and drop it. Use `$1` and `shift`.

```
c=1
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    a[$c]=$1
    c=$((c+1))
    shift
done
```